# How do I apply css to second level menu items?

Tags: asp.net, css, sitemap

I have a menu running off of a sitemap which one of the SiteMapNode looks like this:

```
<siteMapNode title="Gear" description="" url="">
  <siteMapNode title="Armor" description="" url="~/Armor.aspx" />
  <siteMapNode title="Weapons" description="" url="~/Weapons.aspx" />
</siteMapNode>
```

I also have a Skin applied to the asp:menu which uses the following css definition:

```
.nav-bar {
  z-index: 2;
  margin-top: -5%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 281px;
  font-family: Jokewood;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

When I run the website and mouseOver the Gear link, the Jokewood font is not applied to those items, how can I apply the css to the Armor and Weapons titles?

**Update**
I should of mentioned that the font is displayed correctly on all non-nested siteMapNodes.

Comment: Can you please post the generated HTML+CSS (relevant parts) for that page so we don't have to guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should bind styles like this (for both static and dynamic menu items):

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" >
    <StaticMenuStyle CssClass="nav-bar" />
    <DynamicMenuStyle CssClass="nav-bar" />
</asp:Menu>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can nest CSS commands by listing them in sequence

siteMapNode siteMapNode { .... css code ... } would be applied to the inner node.

for instance,

#menu ul ul { ... }

would be applied to 
<ul> <-- not here
<li>
</li>
</ul>
<div id="menu">
 <ul> <-- not here
   <ul>  <---- **here**

Comment: Markdown "fixed" that for you. Should be #menu ul ul {...}

Answer (score 1):

Firefox's [Web Developer (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60) addon is a good alternative/companion to firebug. It's **easier to use for CSS debugging** (IMO)

Answer (score 0):

The skin is applied through a .skin template.

```
<asp:Menu runat="server" CssClass="nav-bar" />
```